# When I use & operand in html textarea, it doesn't appear

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a text area field as shown below, when I enter a string like that : testing123!&aaa it only returns testing123!

```
<span class="value">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Nr2FieldComment, 4, 43, new { @class = "" })
                </span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're having this issue with your ajax request, if true, please use `encodeURIComponent` like bellow;

var commentClean = encodeURIComponent(comment);

Answer (score 0):

The '&' character has special meaning as the lead character in specifying special character values.  Use `&amp;` instead and it should appear.  Lookup all the special character codings to see how and when you need this notation.

Comment: you didn't get my question.  my question is that when a customer needs to write in a text area ( a&b instead of a and b), everything after & including it is cleared and not sent. so only a is sent

Comment: Yes, so you need to base64 encode that string to send it, or you need to use a string parser to replace occurrences of & with &amp; to encode them.  Or use one of the other available encoding mechanisms for URI encoding.